# Loading a two-dimensional array

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm having trouble loading a 2D array. The first row is supposed to be primes between the `p` and `q` values. From my code you can see that I don't exactly know how to load that first row with the primes. I've been reading my text and it's not all that helpful (unless I've overlooked something). Just looking for some advice, thanks.

```
    #include <iostream>

    int main()
    }

  const int ROW = 3;
  const int COL = 4;
  int Table[ROW][COL];
      int p = 24;
      int q = 42;
  for (int i = 0; i < ROW; i++)
      {
    for (p; p < 42; p++)
    {
        if(p % 2 != 0)
        {
            if(p % 3 != 0)
            {
                if(p % 5 != 0)
                {
                    if(p % 7 != 0)
                    {
                        if(p % 11 != 0)
                        {
                            Table[i][j] = p;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

*Edit*: My brackets may be off. This was a copy/paste from Eclipse.

Comment: I don't see where you set j.

Comment: Do you know what `&&` does?

Comment: This was a sloppy attempt to throw together some separate stuff I had done, i.e. printing out primes between my limits, and setting a table. I'm totally lost how to get the first row set with the primes however. I know what && does, not sure how I would apply that here.

Comment: @Matt, to rewrite your code along the lines of [this](http://ideone.com/5fkrEy)?

Comment: That doesn't change anything though, does it? I still have the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int main()
{
    const int Rows = 3;  // avoid uppercase identifiers unless preprocessor macros
    const int Cols = 4;
    int table[Rows][Cols];
    int p = 24;
    int q = 42;
    for (int col = 0; col < Cols; col++)
        for ( ; p < q; ++p)
            if (p % 2  && p % 3 && p % 5 && p % 7 && p % 11)
            {
                table[0][col] = p++; // ++ so not using same p next time...
                break;
            }
}
```

Comment: That works! Thank you. I'm possibly stabbing in the dark here, but to load the second row with a completely different set of values (not primes, something else), would I do `table[row + 1][0]`? My book completely overlooks this fine point. Thanks again.  (I tried that, it seems to work. Might not be the 'best' way, but it works).

Comment: @Matt: fixed above to populate columns in row 0.  To access the next row, you'd write to `table[1][col]` for each column value `col`.

Answer (score 1):

Put a break after `Table[i][j] = p;` so that you will only generate one prime per i.